# How do I fetch my own Instagram media feed

Tags: instagram-api

I have a use case that Instagram does not seem to acknowledge. I am hoping that someone else has an idea for what I can do.

The website that I am maintaining has been using the API endpoint:
https://www.instagram.com/anyUser/media/

And I am aware that Instagram has recently stopped supporting this endpoint. So I am looking for a replacement.

My use case is that I do not want to allow the users of my website to authenticate and browse their own photos. Instead I want to show only the latest 20 images that "I" (aka my employer) have posted, one at a time in a loop.

Instagram's API documentation seems to be entirely focused on the use case of allowing users to authenticate and share their photos.

Is there an API call that will return the last 20 images that I have posted?

From its specs, the Sandbox will work fine for me, I cannot find a way to register with Instagram that does not require me to build a user authentication work flow that will NEVER be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to use self feed endpoint.

https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_self

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN`

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that as soon as possible. Can you please give me some help on getting the token I need to complete this URL.  I'll keep reading the docs but so far, I see guidance there for getting a token for a random user not for myself.

Comment: It's OAuth 2.0 - Detailed flow: `https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/`

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I found that page and could not get through it because I have not built (because I do not need) a privacy policy or redirect url. However, I did find:   http://instagram.pixelunion.net/  which was bale to give me a usable access token.